# Multiplicative Group of a Field Extension is Generated by One Element

Tags: group-theory, field-theory

This is part of a proof I came across:

Let $L/K$ be a finite extension. Suppose $K$ is finite, so $L$ is finite as well. Thus the multiplicative group $L^*$ is generated by one element.

Why is $L^*$ generated by one element?

Answer (score 5):

In general, finite multiplicative subgroups of fields are always cyclic. If the field is finite, then its own unit group is also finite, so it must be cyclic as well. This is a well-known fact, and [you may find many proofs of it here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/54735/collecting-proofs-that-finite-multiplicative-subgroups-of-fields-are-cyclic).